# Как сделать редирект из backenda на главную страницу frontenda?

Tags: yii2

Собственно весь вопрос в том моноли  мне из контролера в backend части сделать редирект на главную страницу frontend и как это сделать? Или придется делать абсолютным адресом редирект?

Comment: В документации описан способ создания ссылок через вспомогательный urlManager: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/docs/guide/topic-link-backend-frontend.md . А если нужно составить абсолютную ссылку с именем домена, можно просто дописать домен в начало.

Comment: @cronfy хорошо и как там мне поставить правило. Хотя честно не понимаю зачем оно мне надо мне ведь некучу совместных правил надо, а редирект в случае если не по тем правилам входит пользователь что бы его не главную выкидывало.

Comment: Я полагаю, что сами редиректы вы делать умеете. В редирект надо передать Url. Url можно создать с помощью UrlManager. Чтобы создать url на фронтенд, вы берете UrlManager фронтенда и методом createAbsoluteUrl() создаете ссылку на нужный route фронтенда, например, site/index.

Comment: Или ваш вопрос заключается в том, как делать редиректы в yii2?

Comment: хорошо а в urlmanager мне правило какое писать к примеру у меня главная http://site.lc это фронтенд как мне правило оформить ? И не легче ли сразу к примеру сразу через createAbsoluteUrl('http://site.lc ')  сделать ?

Comment: Так у вас уже должно быть правило для главной страницы фронтенда. У вас же там тоже yii2 стоит? Обычно `site/index`. А насчет "не легче ли" - так легче всего просто руками нужную ссылку прописать и не мучиться с urlmanager'ом.